# Setting a onclick event to a c# URL Action in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my view I have a checkbox input as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CheckItemsModal" id="@item.ItemId" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("CheckedItem", "List", new { id = item.ItemId })'; Checked(this.id)" />
```

I am trying to have a modal confirmation on the checking and un-checking of the checkbox however this means that my URL action would need to be moved to the modal's button while still preserving the `id = item.ItemId` so my plan is to us javascript to do this however I am not sure how to assign the onclick event of the modal button properly.

This is what I have so far (The error it's throwing is that checkId inside the url action does not exist in the current context):

```
function Checked(checkId) {
   if ($(checkId).Checked == true) {
      $(modalButton).setAttribute('onclick','location.href = '@Url.Action("CheckedItem", "List", new { id = checkId })'')
   }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

C# is run on the server and JavaScript in the browser. Your URL.Action is executed on the server where the `checkId` variable does not exist. You need to generate the url from pure JavaScript in the onclick method or generate links using Url.Action for all checkboxes in advance.

Another option is to use string replace in the JavaScript onclick method. For example:

```
 location.href = '@Url.Action("CheckedItem", "List", new { id = "_REPLACE_ID_" })'.replace( "_REPLACE_ID_", checkId);
```

Look at the generated HTML source to see what happens.

You also need to be careful about your quotes. In your code you have invalid JavaScript with multiple consecutive single quotes at the end.